# How to convert encoding in Python?

Tags: python, encoding

I have a string with miss encoding `»Æ¹ûÊ÷`. On http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en website, you can *encode* it with `gb2312` then *decode* it with `iso8859` so to display it correctly.

In C#, there's a function called [Encoding.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.convert.aspx), which can help you convert convert the bytes from one encoding to the other. In process is straight forward:

```
encode the string into bytesA, using gb2312 encoder
Encoding.Convert bytesA from gb2312 encoding to iso8859 encoding
decode the bytes using iso8859 encoder
```

In Python, I have tried all kinds of encoding and decoding methods I can think of, but no one can help me convert the given string to the correct codecs that can be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data is UTF-8 encoded GB2312, at least as pasted into my UTF-8 configured terminal window:

```
>>> data = '»Æ¹ûÊ÷'
>>> data.decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('gb2312')
u'\u9ec4\u679c\u6811'
>>> print _
黄果树
```

Encoding to Latin 1 lets us interpret characters as bytes to fix the encoding.

Rule of thumb: whenever you have double-encoded data, undo the extra 'layer' of encoding by decoding to Unicode using that codec, then encoding again with Latin-1 to get bytes again.

Comment: This won't work in Python 3 (`str` has no `decode` method). But this will: `"»Æ¹ûÊ÷".encode("latin1").decode("gb2312")`. The string must be encoded in UTF-8, use `#encoding: utf-8` for example.

Comment: @arbautjc: Note that both my method and yours require that the raw string bytes use a certain encoding, yes. My terminal used UTF-8, hence the decode from UTF-8 first.